# How can I monitor the growth stage of a plant leaf using a phone?

Tags: ios, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration, ios-vision

I need to digitally capture the size of a plant leaf at regular intervals to determine its weekly growth rates. I aim for the pixels captured in images at different times to represent the same distance value. Ultimately, I plan to calculate the growth by counting the pixel values using image segmentation. Is this possible with a phone camera (e.g., iPhone 14 Pro), or would I need to use an additional lens?

Could you suggest a method for capturing images with consistent pixel dimensions?